# How does upstream works in nginx (memcached_pass)?

Tags: nginx, memcached

Does nginx go to the next host in upstream block, if previous host not available or doesn't exist?

```
upstream cache_cluster {
   127.0.0.1:9000;     //something on this port
   127.0.0.1:11211;   //memcached instance on this port
}

location  {
 //..some code here
 memcached_pass cache_cluster;
 error_page 404 502 504 =  @something;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

upstream only provide a list of servers, and some kind of weight.  To tell Nginx what to do if one of the servers fail, you need to control this with memcached_next_upstream.

From the [Nginx-documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMemcachedModule#memcached_next_upstream):

> **memcached_next_upstream**
>
> **syntax**: memcached_next_upstream [ error | timeout | invalid_response | not_found | off ]
>
> **default**: error timeout
>
> **context**: http, server, location
>
> Which failure conditions should cause the request to be forwarded to another upstream server? Applies only when the value in memcached_pass is an upstream with two or more servers.

As stated in the documentation, the default behaviour is error / timeout, which should be sufficient in most cases.